# sqlite delete statement with JOIN an UNION

Tags: android, sqlite, query-builder

I have to do a complicated delete-statement, that looks like this:

```
DELETE FROM
(Select t1._id, t1.subject, t1.predicate, t1.object from t1
INNER JOIN t1 AS t2 ON t1.subject=t2.subject
WHERE t2.object='ID20447_325762212'
UNION
Select t1._id, t11.subject, t1.predicate, t1.object from t1
INNER JOIN t1 AS t2 ON t1.object=t2.subject
WHERE t2.object='ID20447_325762212')
```

SQLitedabatase#delete(Table, selection, selectionArgs) is not useable I think. No way to have Joins and Unions.
SQLiteQueryBuilder has JOINs with setTables(joinString) and UNIONs with subQuery() and Unionquery, but only for selectqueries not delete.

How does it work?

[update]
I could reduce complexity by separating both subqueries in two delete-statements, but there is a join in everyone so thats not a solution. And that's not working either.

[update2]
Here's a screenshot from rows of my table i want to delete.
[image: updates screenshot from db-table]

In my app I have an object with ID...2328 (row 2) and a property(relation) represented by the rows in that screenshot. The relation is targeting to an object with id ...212 . I have to delete that object and all Properties

Comment: Your query makes no sense at all. What do pretend? Explain it by words!

Comment: And *which* records do you want to delete? Those from `t1`, or also those from `t2`?

Comment: I'm preparing a little screenshot and edit my question. one moment

Comment: That screenshot is incomprehensible. How many columns are there? What are their names? And what is the `xxxx` in your query?

Comment: I've changed the screenshot, the table has four columns and is very large, in my testings about 3-4MB in just one table. the xxx is the targetid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use complex selections in subqueries.
In the general case, it would look like this:

```
DELETE FROM SomeTable WHERE _id IN (SELECT _id FROM ...complex query...)
```

However, this particular query isn't very complex after all:

```
DELETE FROM t1
WHERE subject = (SELECT subject FROM t1 WHERE object = 'ID20447_325762212')
   OR object  = (SELECT subject FROM t1 WHERE object = 'ID20447_325762212')
```

Comment: What is the difference from your answer to `DELETE FROM t1 WHERE object='ID20447_325762212'`?

Comment: @LS_dev That would delete only the record with ID 19362.

Comment: thx. sqlite data browser handles your code fine, so I implement it in my app.

Comment: @LS_dev The subquery will return the long `SR:ID2052_...212` string. The outer `WHERE` then matches all six blue records.

Comment: @LS_dev That deletes all of the rows in my screenshot by selecting all rows with given id in subject and in object.